# Unable to access data in view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 3 controller methods name as **blog**, **load_messages** and **load_comments**. Now i want to pull the comments when user clicks on the button.
The post id is passed to the method name load_comments but now if i load the view named **blog** so it gives error because i have already passed some data to the view. I just want to pass only that data that is is the comments controller.

The functions are:

```
public function blog() {

    $user_session_email = $this -> session -> userdata('user_email','name','id');
    if(!$user_session_email) {
        redirect('/');
    } 

    $user_data = $this -> users_model -> MyAccount([
        'id' => $this -> session -> userdata('id'),
        'name' => $this -> session -> userdata('name'),
        'email' => $this -> session -> userdata('user_email'),
    ]);
    $data["persoanl"] = $user_data;

    $returned_result = $this -> users_model -> load_messages();
    $messages["message"] = $returned_result['message'];

    $this -> load -> view('users/inc/header', $data);
    $this -> load -> view('users/inc/blog_form', $data);
    $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
    $this -> load -> view('users/inc/footer');
}

public function load_messages() {
    $returned_result = $this -> users_model -> load_messages();
    $messages["message"] = $returned_result["message"];
    $messages['id'] = $this -> load_comments();
    $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
}

public function load_comments() {
    $messages['id'] = $this -> input -> post('post_id');
    $this -> load -> view('users/blog', $messages);
}
```

In the last method i just only want to pass the $message variable, but when i pass this value the other functions in which blog view is loaded with different  parameters like $messages['message'], it generates an error says $message is undefined on blog view page but if i remove the last method it will work perfectly. What should is do how i pass data to blog?

Blog View Code

```
            <?php 
            foreach($message as $blog) :
        ?>
        <div class="row blog_post<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>" id="blog_posts">

            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 user_blog_image">
                <?php if($blog -> profile_image == null) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User Image">
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url().$blog -> profile_image; ?>"  alt="User Image">
                <?php } ?>
            </div> <!-- End of user blog image -->

            <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-9 post_message">
                <?php if($blog -> id == $this -> session -> userdata('id')) : ?>
                <a class="pull-right" onclick="delete_post('<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>', '<?php echo base_url('users/delete_post'); ?>')">
                    &times;
                </a>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <p> 
                    <?php echo $blog -> message; ?> 
                </p>
                <span class="pull-left"> 
                    <small> Posted By: <?php echo $blog -> name; ?></small> 
                </span>
                <a onclick="get_comments(this.id, '<?php echo base_url('users/load_comments'); ?>')" class="stop_interval" id="<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>"> 
                    <i class='fa fa-comment' aria-hidden='true'></i> View Comments
                </a>
                <a onclick="update_like('<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>', '<?php echo base_url('users/update_like'); ?>')">
                    <i class='fa fa-thumbs-up' aria-hidden='true'></i> Likes (<small><?php echo $blog -> likes; ?></small>)
                </a>

            </div> <!-- End of post message -->

            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11 comment_field">

                <div class="show_comments col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="show_comments<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>">
                    <?php echo $id; ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 commentor_pic">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User Image">
                    </div> <!-- End of commentor picture -->
                    <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 comment">
                        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                        <p> <small> Posted By: Rashid Khokhar </small> </p>
                    </div> <!-- End of commentor picture -->
                </div> <!-- End of show comments -->


                <form method="post" id="comment_Form<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>">
                    <input type="text" id="blog_comment<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>" required name="comment_field" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your comment">
                    <button type="submit" id="cmntBtn<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- End of comment field -->

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('public/dist/js/jQuery.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/dist/js/custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            comment_blog('<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>', '<?php echo base_url('users/comment_blog'); ?>');
            jQuery( "#show_comments<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>" ).each(function( value ) {
                jQuery(this).hide();
            });
        </script> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Provide your blog view code for more understand your code

Comment: Code-igniter only accept $data variable as to create a variable in view.

Comment: i updated the question please check

Comment: Change your load_comments() function message to like $messages['msg'] and try

Comment: no still the same issue, if you see i have loaded blog view many times in 3 functions by passing multiple and different parameters so if i load the view again in load_comments function without the other parameters that are sent to blog in above methods then it generates error. I want to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

In load_comments method, you need to fetch the data from database by using model.

Comment: i did but same error, there is one solution but i don't want to go to that the solution is to call other 2 functions and all their variables in the load_comments but i want to resolve this problem without the other two functions